# delete the first element in subview of a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dataset like this:

```
[[0,1],
 [0,2],
 [0,3],
 [0,4],
 [1,5],
 [1,6],
 [1,7],
 [2,8],
 [2,9]]
```

I need to delete the first elements of each subview of the data as defined by the first column. So first I get all elements that have 0 in the first column, and delete the first row: [0,1]. Then I get the elements with 1 in the first column and delete the first row [1,5], next step I delete [2,8] and so on and so forth. In the end, I would like to have a dataset like this:

```
[[0,2],
 [0,3],
 [0,4],
 [1,6],
 [1,7],
 [2,9]]
```

---

EDIT: Can this be done in numpy? My dataset is very large so for loops on all elements take at least 4 minutes to complete.

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you stuck? You'll get more, better, answers to specific questions than to general "please do my problem for me" statements.

Comment: @Robᵩ I've tried to use masks to get each subview and delete the row in the subview, but then I don't know how to delete the row in the original dataset. Will post code soon

Comment: Are these sorted? So, are nested lists with equal values at index 0 grouped?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, sorted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested, a `numpy` solution:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [0,4], [1,5], [1,6], [1,7], [2,8], [2,9]])
_,i = np.unique(a[:,0], return_index=True)

b = np.delete(a, i, axis=0)
```

---

(above is edited to incorporate @Jaime's solution, here is my original masking solution for posterity's sake)

```
m = np.ones(len(a), dtype=bool)
m[i] = False
b = a[m]
```

---

Interestingly, the mask seems to be faster:

```
In [225]: def rem_del(a):
   .....:     _,i = np.unique(a[:,0], return_index=True)
   .....:     return np.delete(a, i, axis = 0)
   .....: 

In [226]: def rem_mask(a):
   .....:     _,i = np.unique(a[:,0], return_index=True)
   .....:     m = np.ones(len(a), dtype=bool)
   .....:     m[i] = False
   .....:     return a[m]
   .....: 

In [227]: timeit rem_del(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 181 us per loop

In [228]: timeit rem_mask(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 59 us per loop
```

Comment: +1 But keeping the same general approach, wouldn't `b = np.delete(a, i, axis=0)` be a better option than those last three lines?

Comment: Thanks @Jaime, I had almost commented to say that the last bit probably has a better implementation :P

Comment: Although, @Jaime, the mask seems to be faster?

Comment: I just looked at [the source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L3503), and `np.delete` does something similar to what you do behind the scenes, but instead of indexing with a boolean array, it creates an array of `np.intp`, and then does a `np.setdiff1d` with the element indices to delete. It may be needed for higher dimensional indexing (not sure, really), but it is definitely slower than your approach. Is the minor readability improvement worth a 3x speed hit? I would tend to say no...

Comment: [numpy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) explicitly state "Often it is preferable to use a boolean mask."

Answer (score 2):

Pass in your lists and the key that you want to check values on.

```
def getsubset(set, index):
    hash = {}
    for list in set:
        if not list[index] in hash:
            set.remove(list)
            hash[list[index]]  = list

    return set
```

Comment: This is fast, but no need to `return set` as this mutates `set` in place.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with a dash of [`itertools.islice()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) and [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import islice, chain, groupby
from operator import itemgetter

list(chain.from_iterable(islice(group, 1, None)
                         for key, group in groupby(inputlist, key=itemgetter(0))))
```

- The `groupby()` call groups the input list into chunks where the first item is the same (`itemgetter(0)` is the grouping key).
- The `islice(group, 1, None)` call turns the groups into iterables where the *first* element will be skipped.
- The `chain.from_iterable()` call takes each `islice()` result and chains them together into a new iterable, which `list()` turns back into a list.

Demo:

```
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(islice(group, 1, None) for key, group in groupby(inputlist, key=itemgetter(0))))
[[0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [1, 6], [1, 7], [2, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [[0,1],
 [0,2],
 [0,3],
 [0,4],
 [1,5],
 [1,6],
 [1,7],
 [2,8],
 [2,9]]

a = [y for x in itertools.groupby(a, lambda x: x[0]) for y in list(x[1])[1:]]

print a
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is :

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(l, key=itemgetter(1))  # fist sort by fist element of inner list 
nl = []
[[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 7], [2, 8], [2, 9]]
j = 0;
for i in range(len(l)): 
    if(j == l[i][0]):
        j = j + 1   # skip element 
    else:
        nl.append(l[i])  # otherwise append  in new list
```

output is:

```
>>> nl
[[0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [1, 6], [1, 7], [2, 9]]
```