# pythonic way to delete elements from a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

If you have `array = np.array([1,2,3,4])` and you have `index = np.array([0,1,2])` and you want to remove the index elements in array, what's the best way to do this without looping?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You use [`numpy.delete`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html):

```
smaller_array = np.delete(array,index)
```

Comment: +1 But for completeness, in [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15706171/110026), @askewchan found out that building a boolean mask is faster than using `np.delete`, i.e `mask = np.ones(array.shape, dtype=np.bool); mask[index] = False; smaller_array = array[mask]`.

Comment: The speed difference should mostly vanish, as delete will be basically a shorthand for that in 1.8. and later (with some faster paths for smaller slices and single integers). Until a bit longer there are some differences for out of bound/negative or boolean indices though.